# VBscript in IE11

Tags: html, excel, vbscript

I need help on this one.

Basically what the codes does is it gets data from an excel file and displays it through htm. This happened because my company won't provide me a database and server for php which would have made things easier.

The thing is that the codes were working on WinXP. But recently, we transitioned to Win7 and suddenly the codes seem to be not working anymore.

The error that I get when I view the IE11 F12 console is that the answerkey() is undefined.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<style type="text/css">

.main{WIDTH: 100%; background-color: #ACDFE7;font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt;}
.main tr td{padding: 2pt 8pt;}
.header{font-size: 2em; text-align: center; font-family: arial;}
</style>
<SCRIPT type="text/vbscript">
function answerkey()
Dim strYourFile : strYourFile ="C:\Users\MilesF\Desktop\Q1\users\answers.xlsx"
Dim strYourSheet : strYourSheet = "Sheet1"
Dim objExcel : Set objExcel     = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.DisplayAlerts          = False
objExcel.Visible                = False
set objWorkbook                 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strYourFile)
set objWorksheet                = objWorkbook.Worksheets(strYourSheet)

names    = document.myguestbook.name.value

If names ="MarianB" Then
document.write("<p align=left><font face=sans-serif size=4><B>Examinee:</B> <U><font color=red>MarianB</font></U></font></p><p align=left><font face=sans-serif size=2><B>Job Process:</b> I - First Investor</font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>1. Identify the two differences of spread and single pdf output? <B>(4pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(3, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>2. What type of command you should do to create a spread output? <B>(2pts)</B> </font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(4, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>3. The document always consists of 4 pages. After the initial your outputs are more than 4 pages what will you do? <B>(2pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(5, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>4. What is the trim size of single and spread? <B>(3pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(6, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=sans-serif size=2><B>Job Process:</b> II - ImmuPharma</font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>1. Where the section pages are usually started in the document? What are the content of the section page? <B>(5pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(10, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>2. What is the purpose of having different sizes/dpi of photos on their list? <B>(3pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(11, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>3. What do we also consider in selecting the photos for the client to buy given the fact that the FPO photos are now in place? <B>(3pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(12, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>4. These are the part of the document that we generate PDF output in spread and in separately. What are these parts? <B>(3pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(13, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=sans-serif size=2><B>Job Process:</b> Liontrust R&A</font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>1. Name the three main section of this type of liontrust. <B>(6pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(17, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>2. This part has a separate of the indesign file and must spread in PDF output. What are these parts? <B>(4pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(18, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>3. This is a supplied PDF from the client and also a part of the document that needs to be placed in a particular section. What do call this insert? Where they should be placed? <B>(5pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(19, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=sans-serif size=2><B>Job Process:</b> MFC 6-K</font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>1. Name at least one of two part of the document does have page border. <B>(2pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(23, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>2. This is the part of the document that usually the client sends or tells to us to follow style source and its page break. <B>(2pts)</B></font></p><p align=left><font face=arial size=2>Answer: <font color=red><B>" & objWorksheet.Cells(24, 2).Value & "</b></font></font></p><BR>")

End If



objWorkbook.Save
Set objWorksheet = Nothing
objWorkbook.Close
set objWorkbook = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
set objExcel = Nothing
End Function
</script>
<Body>
<FORM id=myguestbook name=myguestbook method=post><BR>
    <select name="name">
    <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="MarianB">Marian Berso</option>
    <option value="JiomerD">Jiomer Dacaymat</option>
    <option value="JoyD">Joy Daffon</option>
    <option value="LeoD">John Leo Dela Rosa</option>
    <option value="NestorG">Nestor Garlan Jr.</option>
    <option value="EdelaineP">Edelaine Pasadas</option>
    <option value="RamelP">Ramel Pasadas</option>
    <option value="AbigaelS">Abigael Serrano</option>
    <option value="AlonzoV">Alonzo Villaflor</option>
    </select>

    <INPUT onclick=VBscript:answerkey() type=submit value=SUBMIT name=functional></form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

PS. I am not sure if the codes is actually VBscript cause a colleague of mine just gave it to me and I worked my way into it.

Comment: I would guess it might be because answerkey() is defined a function and does not return anything. Technically this makes it a sub, although vbscript normally is very forgiving there. Can you try if it works if you exchange it to "sub answerkey()" and also "end sub" at the functions end

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But IE11 still flags the same error.

Comment: Hi all, it seems that when I use the F12 Emulation tool and change the document mode to 7, everything seems to be working fine. It's just a little bad that it won't work in IE11 as it is. Anyway, still looking for answers if anyone is able to solve the IE11 mystery.

Comment: It seems as if this is by design: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057%28v=vs8.5%29.aspx . Your solution might be the only thing you can do, and it might be a good idea to get rid of the vbs code altogether for the future...